# Problem trying to load a set of image using an array of UIImage to slide them

Tags: swift, image, animation

I'm trying to load a set of pictures to an imageView so that they slide alon with a time timer.

My problem is that I have the pictures store in Firebase with their URL as Strings. So I use a function to load a single image throug its URL into an imageView and it works. But now I need to find a way to use a function to put a set of images into the imageView so that the slide with a timer and I don´t now how to do it.

[image]

This is the code to load the images from URL

```
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {

func loadFrom(URLAddress: String) {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: URLAddress) else {
            return
        }
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let loadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        self?.image = loadedImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to load the set of image as an UIImage array.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let even = eventos.eventoPulsado()
        var images = [UIImage]()
        print(even.imagenes!)
        //I load the picture this way
        imgFoto.loadFrom(URLAddress: (even.imagenes![0]))
        //But I cannot to append my images because I need UIImage data
        images.append(imgFoto.image!)
  
        for img in (even.imagenes!) {
            imgFoto.loadFrom(URLAddress: (img))
        }
        imgFoto.animationImages = images
        imgFoto.animationDuration = TimeInterval(0.4)
        imgFoto.animationRepeatCount = 4
        imgFoto.startAnimating()
       
    }
```

Comment: Saying `Data(contentsOf: url)` for a remote URL is basically always wrong. There is a correct way to download things and that isn't it.

Comment: and....what's the correct way? and how can achieve my goal?

Comment: URLSession download task is the way to download things. This will so greatly alter the structure / nature of your code that you will basically need to go back to the drawing board. So there's very little point even considering your larger aims until you're downloading correctly.

Comment: It's not a question of starting from scratch, I've been requested by my teacher to use that download function.....so I can't use other alternatives. Really is there no way to animate picture with that code???